# How to float image outside of grid in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.

I want to insert an image with caption into my bodytext but I do not want it to be aligned with the bodytext. I want to display it with an offset like the image shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOuFy.jpg).

Can anyone help?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it would be to style the image with `float: left`, so the text will wrap around it and set a negative left margin so the image will be offset to the left.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="offset">
```

CSS:

```
.offset {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
float:left;margin-right:10px;
```

to your image then your page will be look like that

```html
  

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <div style="float:left;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:20px;"> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" >
<span style="display:block;text-align:center">Caption Here</span></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mmativ, that helps me float the text next to the image, however I don't want the image to be flushed to the same line as the bodytext. I want the image to exceed the grid like I have shown in the image link. Any idea?

Comment: check the snippet, ohh my wrong, yes, you need to margin-left